# Remove content of textarea when iframe is done?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

So currently my website works like this; you post an update and through iframe your update gets added to the database and then shown in a list below. But the problem is that when you clicked "Submit" the text you wrote is still shown in the textarea because the website doesn't update completely. I have tried to have "onsubmit" and "onclick" but both remove the content of the textarea before it gets added to the database so it displays an empty message.

What should I do in order to delay it just a second or how do I make it wait for the iframe to "send" data to my PHP-script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your textarea an id and supposing that iframe is an element of the page that contains the textarea you have done the following in the iframe page:

```
<?php
//code should be done after db add
?>
<script>
o = parent.document.getElementById('textareaID');
o.value = '';
</script>
<?php 
//the end of code or something else
?>
```

You are able to see those demos on [jsbin](/questions/tagged/jsbin):

- http://jsbin.com/ulOyiVo/1 *The page with iframe*. Supply the textarea with any text and then click on simulate submit link
- http://jsbin.com/EyuBeLo/1/ *The iframe page*

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is to have a delayed response, you could trigger a `setTimeout` function to your `onClick`, with the given `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(
  function() {
    alert('hello');
  },1250 //in milliseconds
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `click` or a `submit` event using jQuery and send a request to your server. You can handle the event when the server responded using a `callback`. In that `callback` you need to do whatever it is needed to do. Using `setTimeout` in this case is an unnecessary hack. You will either set up a big time to wait harming the user experience or in case the page responds later than the specified time your page will work unexpectedly. So, instead of that try defining an event.